# Please explain this code for Merkle–Hellman knapsack cryptosystem?

Tags: cryptography

This is the code snippet from a program that implements Merkle–Hellman knapsack cryptosystem.

```
// Generates keys based on input data size
private void generateKeys(int inputSize) 
{
    // Generating values for w
    // This first value of the private key (w) is set to 1
    w.addNode(new BigInteger("1"));
    for (int i = 1; i < inputSize; i++) 
    {
        w.addNode(nextSuperIncreasingNumber(w));
    }
    // Generate value for q
    q = nextSuperIncreasingNumber(w);

    // Generate value for r
    Random random = new Random();

    // Generate a value of r such that r and q are coprime
    do 
    {
        r = q.subtract(new BigInteger(random.nextInt(1000) + ""));
    }
    while ((r.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) > 0) && (q.gcd(r).intValue() != 1));

    // Generate b such that b = w * r mod q
    for (int i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) 
    {
        b.addNode(w.get(i).getData().multiply(r).mod(q));
    }
}
```

Just tell me what is going on in the following lines:

```
    do 
    {
        r = q.subtract(new BigInteger(random.nextInt(1000) + ""));
    }
    while ((r.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) > 0) && (q.gcd(r).intValue() != 1));
```

(1) Why is random number generated with upper bound 1000?

(2) Why is it subtracted from q?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is searching for a value that is co-prime with the already selected value `q`. In my opinion, it's doing so rather poorly, but you mention it's a simulator? I'm not sure what that means, but maybe it just means the code is quick and dirty rather than slow and secure.

Answering your questions directly:

> 1. Why is random number generated with upper bound 1000?

The [Merkle-Hellman algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle%E2%80%93Hellman_knapsack_cryptosystem) *does* indicate that `r` should be 'random'. The implementation for doing so is pretty haphazard; that might be what's thrown you off. The code is not technically an algorithm because the loop is not guaranteed to terminate. In theory, the psuedo-random candidate selection of `r` could be an arbitrarily long sequence of numbers which aren't co-prime to `q`, resulting in an infinite loop.

The upper bound of 1000 could be to ensure that the chosen `r` is sufficiently large. In general, large keys are harder to break than small keys, so if `q` is large, then this code will only find large `r`.

A more deterministic way to get a random co-prime would be to test each number lower than `q`, generating a list of co-primes and select one at random. This would probably be more secure, as an attacker knowing that `q` and `r` are within 1000 of each other would have a significantly reduced search space.

> 2. Why is it subtracted from q?

The subtraction is important because `r` must be less than `q`. The Merkle-Hellmen algorithm specifies it that way. I'm not convince that it needs to be that way. The public key is generated by multiplying each element in *w* by *r* and taking the modulus *q*. If *r* were very large, larger than *q*, it seems like it would further obfuscate *q* and each element in *w*.

The decryption step of Merkle-Hellmen, on the other hand, depends on the [modular inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of each encrypted letter *a* x *r*<sup>−1</sup> mod *q*. This operation might be hampered by having `r` > `q`; it seems like it could still work out.

However, if `nextInt` can return 0, that iteration of the loop is a waste as a `q` and `r` must be different (`gcd(a,a)` is just `a`).

Breaking down the code:

```
do
```

Try it at least once. `r` is probably null or undefined before the method is called.

```
    r = q.subtract(new BigInteger(random.nextInt(1000) + ""));
```

Find a candidate value that's between `q` and `q - 1000`.

```
while ((r.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) > 0) && (q.gcd(r).intValue() != 1));
```

Keep going until you've found an `r` that is:

- Greater than 0 `r.compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) > 0`, and
- Is co-prime with `q`,  `q.gcd(r).intValue() != 1`. Obviously, a randomly selected number is not guaranteed to be co-prime with another other number, so the randomly generated candidate might not be work for this `q`.

Does that clear it up? I have to admit that I'm not an expert on Merkle-Hellman.

Comment: How can the code be modified to make it neater and more efficient?

Comment: I'm not sure efficiency is what you want. Security is the benchmark of a cryptosystem, and that ship has sailed for Merkle-Hellman. Wikipedia references Shamir, Adi (1984). "A polynomial-time algorithm for breaking the basic Merkle - Hellman cryptosystem". Information Theory, *IEEE Transactions* on 30 (5): 699–704. But you could definitely improve this particular implementation by finding all numbers less than and coprime to `q` before selecting one randomly, and doing so as efficiently as possible would not harm the security.